# C++: Number Arranging Program Not Working Properly

Tags: c++

I have tried making a program to sort numbers of an array.

I have done my best but there is this problem: Although I do a loop to swap the numbers and arrange them, when I output the array, nothing changes and the array remains the same.

The code will make everything clearer

This is the main function:

```
int main(){
int arr[10];
//For loop to get from user numbers to be put into the array
for ( int i = 0; i<10; i++){
    cout << "Enter the number to be recorded: ";
    cin >> arr[i];
    cout << endl;
}
// Set counter n to 0 ( counts numbes of number swaps)
int n = 0;
do {
    //re sets counter to 0
    n=0;

    //Check the entire loop if arr[i] bigger than arr[i+1] and swaps their values if true then adds 1 to n
    for ( int i = 0; i>9; i++){
        if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]){
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[i+1]);//swaps by sending the addresses of the two array elements the pointers in the swap function
            n++;
        }
    }
}while(n>0); // if counter = 0 then end (therefore the numbers are arranged correctly since no swapping happened)
cout << "The numbers ordered are:\n\n";
// Loop to output the arranged array
for (int i =0; i<10; i++){
    cout << arr[i] << ", ";
}
cout<<endl;
system("PAUSE");
return 0;}
```

This is the swap function:

```
void swap ( int *p, int *t){
int temp;
temp = *p;
*p = *t;
*t = temp;}
```

I hope you guys can help me with my problem here and tell me what's wrong with this code

Thank you all

Comment: 1) Don't use `system("pause");`. 2) Prefer `std::swap` to making your own. 3) Prefer `std::sort`, but I assume the whole point of this is that you can't do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look closely at your for loop...its contents will never be executed.

```
for ( int i = 0; i>9; i++){ ... }
```

The condition `i>9` should be `i<9`.

Answer (score 1):

```
   for ( int i = 0; i>9; i++){
                    ^^^
                     here is your problem
```

you have initialized the `i to the 0` and checking the condition is that if `i is greater than 9` which is not **never true** so the **condition** of **the for loop** is **false** and so it will be terminated

it should be

```
for( int i = 0; i<9; i++) than the
```

result

```
   i=0 condition i<9 true  { come in the function body}
   i=1 condition i<9 true  { come in the function body}
   .
   .
   .
   i=8 condition i<9 true  { come in the function body}
   i=9 condition i<9 false  { }
```

Comment: Thank you. I dont know how I didnt see it. I can be such an idiot sometimes. I can't tank you enough.